# Programmatically swap colors from a loaded bitmap to Red, Green, Blue or Gray, pixel by pixel

Tags: delphi, colors, bitmap

Download source code here: http://www.eyeClaxton.com/download/delphi/ColorSwap.zip

Yes, I want to convert something "mostly blue" to something "mostly green".

I would like to take a original bitmap (light blue) and change the colors (Pixel by Pixel) to the red, green, blue and gray equivalence relation.  To get an idea of what I mean, I have include the source code and a screen shot. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If more information is needed, please feel free to ask.

If you could take a look at the code below, I have three functions that I'm looking for help on.  The functions "RGBToRed, RGBToGreen and RGBToRed" I can't seem to come up with the right formulas.

[image]

```
unit MainUnit;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
  TMainFrm = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    BeforeImage1: TImage;
    AfterImage1: TImage;
    RadioGroup1: TRadioGroup;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainFrm: TMainFrm;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}
function RGBToGray(RGBColor: TColor): TColor;
var
  Gray: Byte;
begin
  Gray := Round(
    (0.90 * GetRValue(RGBColor)) +
    (0.88 * GetGValue(RGBColor)) +
    (0.33 * GetBValue(RGBColor)));

  Result := RGB(Gray, Gray, Gray);
end;

function RGBToRed(RGBColor: TColor): TColor;
var
  Red: Byte;
begin
  // Not sure of the algorithm for this color
  Result := RGB(Red, Red, Red);
end;

function RGBToGreen(RGBColor: TColor): TColor;
var
  Green: Byte;
begin
  // Not sure of the algorithm for this color
  Result := RGB(Green, Green, Green);
end;

function RGBToBlue(RGBColor: TColor): TColor;
var
  Blue: Byte;
begin
  // Not sure of the algorithm for this color
  Result := RGB(Blue, Blue, Blue);
end;

procedure TMainFrm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BeforeImage1.Picture.LoadFromFile('Images\RightCenter.bmp');
end;

procedure TMainFrm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
  I, X: Integer;
  Color: Integer;
begin
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.LoadFromFile('Images\RightCenter.bmp');

    for X := 0 to Bitmap.Height do
    begin
      for I := 0 to Bitmap.Width do
      begin
        Color := ColorToRGB(Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[I, X]);

        case Color of
          $00000000: ;   // Skip any Color Here!
        else
          case RadioGroup1.ItemIndex of
            0: Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[I, X] := RGBToBlue(Color);
            1: Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[I, X] := RGBToRed(Color);
            2: Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[I, X] := RGBToGreen(Color);
            3: Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[I, X] := RGBToGray(Color);
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    AfterImage1.Picture.Graphic := Bitmap;
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Okay, I apologize for not making it clearer.  I'm trying to take a bitmap (blue in color) and swap the blue pixels with another color. Like the shots below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. In what way does the code you provided not already do what you need?

Comment: Ok, I like the face that you've provided a screenshot and code, but I don't get what you want from us. What is the question, or what part is not working the way you want?

Comment: If you could take a look at the code above, I have three functions that I'm looking for help on.  The functions "RGBToRed, RGBToGreen and RGBToRed" I can't seem to come up with the right formulas.

Comment: So you want everything red to become green too (look at the X of the window). There are a thousand ways to make something "mostly blue" into something "mostly green", I hope you know that.

Comment: Okay, I'll regroup and try and ask the question another way later.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. First, what does the question have to do with [equivalence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation)?

Secondly, the code

```
function RGBToRed(RGBColor: TColor): TColor;
var
  Red: Byte;
begin
  // Not sure of the algorithm for this color
  Result := RGB(Red, Red, Red);
end;
```

is meaningless. The return value is undefined. The `RGB` functions takes red, green, and blue intensities in the range 0 to 255 and returns the `TColor` having these components. For instance, `RGB(255, 0, 0)` is pure red, that is, 255 red, 0 green, and 0 blue. In the code above, however, `Red` is not initialized, so `Result` can be any grey colour (depending on what `Red` happens to be). [And, as you probably know, if you mix equal amounts of red, green, and blue, as you do, you get grey.] For instance, `Red` might happen to be 45 one time you run the application, and then the result will be the grey colour `RGB(45, 45, 45)`. Next time it might be 163.

Maybe you want a function that accepts a `TColor` and returns the red component of it? Then `GetRValue` will do, and - of course - there is also `GetGValue` and `GetBValue`.

Or, maybe you want to create a grey colour from a given `TColor`, as you do when you use Photoshop to create a greyscale image from a colour image. Then, if `Color` is the `TColor`, the appropriate grey value is

```
grey := (GetRValue(Color) + GetGValue(Color) + GetBValue(Color)) div 3;
```

There are other ways of doing this (resulting in subtly different greyscale images, but this is the easiest (and fastest)). (For instance, you can convert the colour from RGB to HSV or HSL and then set the saturation equal to zero.)

**Update**

I think I see what you want to do. Maybe you want to extract the red, green, and blue channels. That is, you want to transform each pixel `RGB(R, G, B)` to `RGB(R, 0, 0)` in the red case. If this is what you want to do, then you should do

```
function RGBToRed(RGBColor: TColor): TColor;
begin
  Result := RGB(GetRValue(RGBColor), 0, 0);
end;
```

and similarly for the other components, that is

```
function RGBToGreen(RGBColor: TColor): TColor;
begin
  Result := RGB(0, GetGValue(RGBColor), 0);
end;
```

and

```
function RGBToBlue(RGBColor: TColor): TColor;
begin
  Result := RGB(0, 0, GetBValue(RGBColor));
end;
```

**Or, maybe**

Or maybe you just want to make the image greyscale, and then "colour" it red (or green, or blue). Then you need the heavy machinery. Theoretically, you wish to replace each pixel from `HSV(h, s, v)` to `HSV(0, s, v)` in the red case, `HSV(120, s, v)` in the green case, and `HSV(240, s, v)` in the blue case. Or, maybe you also wish to set the saturation `s` to 1.

I use the following rutines to convert between RGB and HSV:

```
function RGBToHSV(const Color: TRGB): THSV;
var
  cmax, cmin, cdiff: real;
begin
  cmax := MaxComponent(Color);
  cmin := MinComponent(Color);
  cdiff := cmax - cmin;

  with Color, result do
  begin

    // Hue
    if cmax = cmin then
      hsvHue := 0
    else if cmax = rgbRed then
      hsvHue := (60 * (rgbGreen - rgbBlue) / cdiff)
    else if cmax = rgbGreen then
      hsvHue := (60 * (rgbBlue - rgbRed) / cdiff) + 120
    else
      hsvHue := (60 * (rgbRed - rgbGreen) / cdiff) + 240;

    hsvHue := Fix360(hsvHue);

    // Saturation
    if cmax = 0 then
      hsvSaturation := 0
    else
      hsvSaturation := 1 - cmin / cmax;

    // Value
    hsvValue := cmax;

  end;

end;
```

and

```
function HSVToRGB(const Color: THSV): TRGB;
var
  hi: integer;
  f, q, p, t: real;
begin

  with Color do
  begin

    hi := floor(hsvHue / 60) mod 6;
    f := hsvHue / 60 - floor(hsvHue / 60);
    p := hsvValue * (1 - hsvSaturation);
    q := hsvValue * (1 - f * hsvSaturation);
    t := hsvValue * (1 - (1 - f) * hsvSaturation);

    case hi of
      0: result := RGB(hsvValue, t, p);
      1: result := RGB(q, hsvValue, p);
      2: result := RGB(p, hsvValue, t);
      3: result := RGB(p, q, hsvValue);
      4: result := RGB(t, p, hsvValue);
      5: result := RGB(hsvValue, p, q);
    end;

  end;

end;
```

where

```
type
  TRGB = record
    rgbRed,            // red intensity between 0 and 1
    rgbGreen,          // green intensity between 0 and 1
    rgbBlue: double;   // blue intensity between 0 and 1
  end;

  THSV = record
    hsvHue,            // hue angle between 0 and 360
    hsvSaturation,     // saturation between 0 (grey) and 1 (full colour)
    hsvValue: double;  // value between 0 (dark) and 1 ("normal")
  end;
```

The end result, in the green case, will be like

[image: Hue fixed to 120]

in the first case (hue fixed to 120) and

[image: Hue fixed to 120 and saturation fixed to 1]

in the latter case (hue fixed to 120, saturation fixed to 1).

**Or, possibly**

Your question is very vauge, even with the edit. You want to convert something "mostly blue" to something "mostly green". But there are a thousand ways of doing that! A very simple way, of course, is just to swap the blue and green channels, that is, replace `RGB(r, g, b)` with `RGB(r, b, g)`, or, explicitly,

```
function SwapBlueGreen(Color: TColor): TColor;
begin
  result := RGB(GetRValue(Color), GetBValue(Color), GetGValue(Color));
end;
```

Then you get something like

[image: R and G channels swapped]

where the red and green channels have been swapped. Notice that the red stick is now green, and the green grass is now red. What's white remains white.

**Finally**

Welcome to the world of pixmap manipulation! There is a lot of easy and fun things to do. Some more of my examples: https://english.rejbrand.se/algosim/manual/pmproc/pmproc.html

Comment: Yes, I want to convert something "mostly blue" to something "mostly green".

Comment: +1 Brilliant comprehensive answer! maybe one day I can understand the logic behind such code :)

Answer (score 2):

Accessing color information via "Pixels" property is really slow. You should consider using "Scanline" property to get about 2 levels of magnitude faster code.
http://blogs.embarcadero.com/pawelglowacki/2010/04/15/39051 contains code samples how to do it.

Success!